# How to display the json data in drupal 8 page?

Tags: drupal-8

How to display the json data in drupal 8 page?

Hi Team,
I am looking out for possible solutions to display the data from external API in a drupal page.

1. calling the API on page load.
2. API call results a json array
3. need to pick the data from the result and display in the following format in drupal 8 page.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MwvEU.png)

Please suggest the best approach for this requirement. Note: we are not supposed to store the fetch data in drupal db. we need to use drupal page to display the content alone.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to build a custom module to:

1. Add a service which will fetch the data from your API call using `\GuzzleHttp\Client::request()`
2. Create a custom route which will use the service and return a renderable array of data
3. Create a template which will be used by your custom route to format the data as you want it to be displayed